# git -submodules / repo - How to use commit and branch for a bunch of branches in separate modules?

Tags: git, git-submodules, repository

I have [`repo`](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html) wrapper and about dozen different git repositories in it.

I would like to have one patch which I can apply/use later 
in the following manner:

I would like to perform this commands on all the changed submodules:

```
git checkout -b all_sub_branch
git commit -a all_submodules
git format-patch all_submodules aaa.patch
git apply aaa.patch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain vanilla git answer (using submodules):

This kind of process done for each submodule could be initiated with:

```
git submodule foreach [--recursive] ...
```

With '...' referring to a git alias which would include all your commands.

From [`git submodule` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule):

```
foreach
```

> Evaluates an arbitrary shell command in each checked out submodule.
>   The command has access to the variables `$name`, `$path`, `$sha1` and `$toplevel`:
>
> - `$name` is the name of the relevant submodule section in `.gitmodules`,
> - `$path` is the name of the submodule directory relative to the superproject,
> - `$sha1` is the commit as recorded in the superproject, and
> - `$toplevel` is the absolute path to the top-level of the superproject.
>
> Any submodules defined in the superproject but not checked out are ignored by this command.
>   Unless given `--quiet`, `foreach` prints the name of each submodule before evaluating the command.
>   If `--recursive` is given, submodules are traversed recursively (i.e. the given shell command is evaluated in nested submodules as well).

---

The issue is that the [android `repo` wrapper command](http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html) does what git submodule does in its own unique way.
So an equivalent of `git submodule foreach` might be: [`repo forall`](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html#forall), e.g.:

`repo forall -c 'git status'`

Comment: How can I do it using repo ?

Comment: @0x90 you wouldn't be able to do it right away, since that repo command doesn't maintain git submodules links between a parent repo and its "projects". I have edited the answer to include a possible "`repo`" command.